# Is this a continuous function or not? Why?

Tags: calculus

Here's an interesting question:

Does the schematic graph of a function below represent a continuous or discontinuous function? Why?

[image]

(This is not homework; just starting a recreational discussion)

EDIT: For clarificatio, the domain intended is $\left(\infty, -1\right] \cup \left[1, -\infty \right) $

Comment: What is the domain of the function?

Comment: What do you know about the definition of "continuous"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intention is that the domain of the function is something like $(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)$, then it can certainly be continuous on that domain.

(With the usual reservations that there may be discontinuities that are too small to see on you graph, etc.)

Comment: Yes that was the domain intended (clarification appended). But how could it be continuous? We are not able to evaluate limits for $x$-values less than $1$, say $0 < x < 1 $. How else are the left and right-hand side limits supposed to coincide?

Comment: @thelionkingrafiki: In order to be continuous, it needs to equal its limit _at every point in the domain_. What it does _outside_ its domain is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is discontinuous if it goes from (-inf, inf) or from (-1,1), or (-2, 5). It's not discontinuous if you use it from all points other than the hole you made for example (2, 4) or (-inf, -3)

Answer (score 0):

The continuity of a function depends on it's domain. For example $y=\tan^{-1}x$ is continuous on $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ but it's not continuous on $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\,\pi\right)$

Comment: I think you mean $y=tanx$.

Answer (score 0):

Your function seems to be continuous. As a matter of fact even a function like:
$$
f(x) = \frac 1 x
$$
which have a graph like the following:
[image]

is continuous!

Comment: I'd like to point out that it's continuous for $x\not=0$

Comment: But what about $x \neq 0$? Are you telling me the definition of continuous only intends the natural domain of the function in question? Isn't that just circumventing the problem (i.e. the singularities, jump discontinuities etc.)?

Comment: A function is continuous if it is continuous at every point of its domain.